# How to de-source the source items in .bashrc without comment?

Tags: bash, bashrc

How to de-source the source items in .bashrc without comment?
I want to make the source item do not work in the .bashrc file. The specific item is 'source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate' in .bashrc.  I do not want to comment it cause it is inconvenience.
So I think is there someway to do that?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible directly.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760614/11970791). You have to manually undo all the operations that the script **~/miniconda3/bin/activate** has done.

Comment: If typing `#` is an inconvenience, what won't be?

Comment: The full process is ' vi ~/.bashrc, Shift + G, i, #, ESC, :wq, source ~/.bashrc', so I do not think it is convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, typically one can't "undo" something that is "sourced", since it directly changes the current environment. The only way to have the changes "undone" is if, somehow, the old environment was stored, so it could be set back to its original values.

For example, if a file `foo.env` is sourced (`source foo.env`) and it changes `PATH` to include `$HOME/mystuff/bin/`, then the only way to undo those changes would be for `foo.env` to remember what `PATH` was originally, e.g., by setting something like `OLD_PATH=$PATH`, then you run something that will set everything back to its original values. (Note that this isn't always reliable, and any changes made after sourcing `foo.env` would be lost.)

In the case of anaconda (miniconda), which is the command you reference in your `.bashrc`, there does happen to be such a program, though. It's invoked by running something like `deactivate` or `conda deactivate`, which should "undo" the changes to the environment caused by `~/miniconda3/bin/activate`.

See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment